# What's the minimum view element rendering time when I should consider caching it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, ruby-on-rails-4, memcached, haml

Using New Relic I can analyse average rendering time of partials in my view. My `navbar` partial for example only takes 2-5ms to render and `footer` takes less 0.5ms. Does it make sense caching them considering that the retrieval time from memcached may take just as long if not longer?

Answer (score 0):

Don't cache it until you need to.  At those speeds you don't need to.  Assuming that that is including database query time and not just view rendering time.

Comment: Well some of those small partials/elements invoke a small database query within them, some are just static. What's the difference if both still take little to render?

Comment: No difference.  I was just making sure that your 2ms of time was total time, not just for the view.